# Move map and load more data from API

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview

I am using an `MKMapView` that loads data from an API and places locations on the map. When the user scrolls the map, I want to load additional locations from the API and populate the map with those locations, etc etc. The API takes map bounds as a param.

What I have tried:

```
- (void)mapView:(id)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    
    
    [self getNewCachesForLiveMap];
    
}

- (BOOL)currentMapRectIsNew {
    
    NSInteger minZoomLevel = 12;
    NSInteger zoom = [self getCurrentZoomLevel];
    NSArray *currentAnnotations = [self annotationsInCurrentMapRect];
    
    return currentAnnotations.count == 0 && zoom >= minZoomLevel;
    
}

// Live Map
- (void)getNewCachesForLiveMap {
    
    BOOL useLiveMap = YES;
    if ([self currentMapRectIsNew] && useLiveMap && DEBUG && !self.isMakingLiveMapRequest) {
        
        NSLog(@"***** Live Load *******");
        [SVProgressHUD show];
        
        // Load from API
        [self loadLocationsForCurrentMapLocation];
        
    }
    
    //self.previousMapRect = [self currentMapRect];
    
}
```

This does correctly load from the API if I am at zoom level 12 or above, but it requires I move the map to where there are no loaded locations.

**My question is, is there a better and more efficient way of doing this?**

Comment: Where does a guy named getCurrentZoomLevel come from?

Comment: @ElTomato That method is just doing some math to calculate the zoom level.

Comment: Use `mapView:clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations delegate` mothod.

Comment: @ElTomato That isn't what I am needing.